# Break OnItemLongClickListener when dragging view

Tags: android, draggable, onclicklistener, touch-event, ontouchlistener

in my android application, I've made a view draggable with a `OnTouchListener`. This works still fine. The listener is set to a `ListView`. Now the problem is how to set the `onTouch` and the `setOnItem(Long)ClickListener(s)` at one time. 
What I've already tried:

1. Set both listeners, the onTouch Event returns false. When I drag the ListView the `OnItemLongClickListener` Event is fired. -> Can drag the view, but a Dialog appears.
2. Set both listeners, the onTouch Event returns true. -> The item click listeners are never fired
3. Set both listeners, the onTouch Event returns false, but when the X-difference is big enough (between startX and nowX) for a drag gesture then it returns true. So what I thought 
   was: It returns false for a click. But when the view will be dragged it returns true, so the listeners are not fired. -> On each drag the `OnLongItemClick` event is fired - even when I 
   lift the finger from the touchscreen. Obviously an `OnLongItemClick` event is detected in the `return false` time, and when the `OnTouch` listener returns true it still runs - and is not breaking.

How could I solve this problem? My Idea was it to break the `OnLongItemClick` event when a drag is recognized. But I've just don't have founded a way how to do so.

If you need a even more complicated explainaiton for #3, please leave a comment.

Thanks a lot.